# How do I upload a plist to a godaddy server on iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, file-upload, sdk, upload

In my code, the program will create a simple .plist file. I have a ftp server i bought from godaddy. I know that in order to upload things to that server I need a username and password. All the tutorials I've been seeing have no place to put a username and password! So basically, I need to know how to upload a simple .plist to my godaddy server.

Comment: The answer depends on how you want to upload it. It sounds like you are thinking of FTP, but you should confirm that and then edit your question.

Comment: I noticed in this video around 6:25 he mentions how to specify your user name and password while writing a plist. http://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=plpp&v=3Oy-evy2xD8 Hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -3):

You can upload files via your Go Daddy account or via FTP.

To Upload Files Using Your Go Daddy Account:

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. In the Content section of the Hosting Control Center, click the FTP File Manager icon.
5. Use the directory tree to navigate to the folder where you would like to upload the file.
6. In the menu bar, click Upload.
   NOTE: You can upload up to 20MB at a time.
   Click Browse and select the files to upload. You can select multiple files.
7. Click Upload.

Comment: I did and was unsure what method they are trying to use.  I tried to give an alternative option to upload to their hosting account.  I guess I misunderstood the question.